# How to parse through folders and files using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, logging

I am trying to construct a script that moves through specific folders and the log files in it, and filters the error codes. After that it passes them into a new file.

I'm not really sure how to do that with for loops so I'll leave my code bellow.

If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
$file_name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Name of the new file: '

$path = 'C:\Users\user\Power\log_script\logs'

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
function Unzip
{
    param([string]$zipfile, [string]$outpath)

    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath)
}

if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($path)) {
    Remove-Item $path
    Unzip 'C:\Users\user\Power\log_script\logs.zip' 'C:\Users\user\Power\log_script'
} else {
    Unzip 'C:\Users\user\Power\log_script\logs.zip' 'C:\Users\user\Power\log_script'
}

$folder = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\user\Power\log_script\logs\LogFiles'

$files = foreach($logfolder in $folder) {
    $content = foreach($line in $files) {
        if ($line -match '([ ][4-5][0-5][0-9][ ])') {
        echo $line
        }
    }
}


$content | Out-File $file_name -Force -Encoding ascii
```

Inside the LogFiles folder are three more folders each containing log files.
Thanks

Comment: One thing you should look into is the -Recurse parameter for the Get-Childitem.  This will cause it to search subfolders.

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately it isn't doing what it is supposed to.

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on a comment above about recursing the folder structure, and then actually retrieving the content of the files, you could try something line this:

```
$allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\user\Power\log_script\logs\LogFiles' -Recurse

# iterate the files
$allFiles | ForEach-Object {
    # iterate the content of each file, line by line
    Get-Content $_ | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '([ ][4-5][0-5][0-9][ ])') {
            echo $_
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the outer `ForEach-Object`, and after removing it you won't need `$_` in the `Get-Content` command.  `Get-Content` can take pipeline input directly from `Get-ChildItem`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your inner loop is of a collection (`$files`) that doesn't yet exist.  You assign `$files` to the output of a `ForEach(...)` loop then try to nest another loop of `$files` inside it. Of course at this point `$files` isn't available to be looped.

Regardless, the issue is you are never reading the content of your log files.  Even if you managed to loop through the output of `Get-ChildItem`, you need to look at each line to perform the match.

Obviously I cannot completely test this, but I see a few issues and have rewritten as below:

```
$file_name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Name of the new file'
$path      = 'C:\Users\user\Power\log_script\logs'
$Pattern   = '([ ][4-5][0-5][0-9][ ])'

if ( [System.IO.File]::Exists( $path ) ) { Remove-Item $path }

Expand-Archive 'C:\Users\user\Power\log_script\logs.zip' 'C:\Users\user\Power\log_script'

Select-String -Path 'C:\Users\user\Power\log_script\logs\LogFiles\*' -Pattern $Pattern |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty line |
Out-File $file_name -Force -Encoding ascii
```

Note: `Select-String` cannot recurse on its own.

I'm not sure you need to write your own `UnZip` function.  PowerShell has the `Expand-Archive` cmdlet which can at least match the functionality thus far:

```
Expand-Archive -Path <SourceZipPath> -DestinationPath <DestinationFolder>
```

Note: The `-Force` parameter allows it to over write the destination files if they are already present. which may be a substitute for testing if the file exists and deleting if it does.

If you are going to test for the file that section of code can be simplified as:

```
if ( [System.IO.File]::Exists( $path ) ) { Remove-Item $path }

Unzip 'C:\Users\user\Power\log_script\logs.zip' 'C:\Users\user\Power\log_script'
```

This is because you were going to run the `UnZip` command regardless...

Note: You could also use `Test-Path` for this.

Also there are enumerable ways to get the matching lines, here are a couple of extra samples:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\user\Power\log_script\logs\LogFiles' |
ForEach-Object{
    ( Get-Content $_.FullName ) -match $Pattern
    # Using match in this way will echo the lines that matched from each run of
    # Get-Content.  If nothing matched nothing will output on that iteration.
} |
Out-File $file_name -Force -Encoding ascii
```

This approach will read the entire file into an array before running the match on it. For large files it may pose a memory issue, however it enabled the clever use of -match.

OR:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\user\Power\log_script\logs\LogFiles' |
Get-Content |
ForEach-Object{ If( $_ -match $Pattern ) { $_ } } |
Out-File $file_name -Force -Encoding ascii
```

Note: You don't need the alias echo or its real cmdlet `Write-Output`

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: After fuzzing around a bit and trying different things I finally got it to work.

I'll include the code below just for demonstration purposes.

Thanks everyone

```
$start = Get-Date
"`n$start`n"

$file_name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Name of the new file: '

Out-File $file_name -Force -Encoding ascii 

Expand-Archive -Path 'C:\Users\User\Power\log_script\logs.zip' -Force
$i = 1 
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\User\Power\log_script\logs\logs\LogFiles' -Name -Recurse -Include *.log

foreach($item in $folders) {
    $files = 'C:\Users\User\Power\log_script\logs\logs\LogFiles\' + $item
    foreach($file in $files){
        $content = Get-Content $file
        Write-Progress -Activity "Filtering..." -Status "File $i of $($folders.Count)" -PercentComplete (($i / $folders.Count) * 100)
        $i++ 
        $output = foreach($line in $content) {
            if ($line -match '([ ][4-5][0-5][0-9][ ])') {
            Add-Content -Path $file_name -Value $line
            }
        }
    }
}

$end = Get-Date
$time = [int]($end - $start).TotalSeconds

Write-Output ("Runtime: " + $time + " Seconds" -join ' ')
```